# Microsoft Document Explorer from Visual Studio startup time

Tags: visual-studio

When pressing  inside Visual Studio .NET 2005/2008, it takes about 1-2 minutes for the Document Explorer to load (when it not was opened before).

Freshly installed it appears almost immediately, but then something was broken.

If MSDE starts from Start menu - everything is OK.

Does anyone know how to speed up document explorer again?

Answer (score 1):

I'm suffering the same problem, "Document Explorer" takes ages to load.

After going to Tools->Options->Environment->Help->Online and unchecking all the 
"Codezone Community" checkboxes "Document Explorer" loads faster.

My Internet connection is behind a proxy, I'm guessing that it takes time to establish the connection with all the "Codezone Community" websites.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've checked this option before asking and even tried to set "Try local only, not online". Only "Local Help" is checked in the provider list.

Unfortunately it doesn't help. Btw, I have quick inet with public IP, so I think connection is not the problem here in any case.

But thank for you guess :)